# Perl regex with grep to get the substring

Tags: regex, perl, grep

```
4:46:31.232 AM  INFO    2012-08-13 04:46:31,232 [81-Spl/[1406]/[]]  - Adj Quantity Exceeds Paramaters. CFE 370 880N EMP NF 201209 -100 ADJOI
```

I need to get anything from Adj till ADJOI. 
"Adj Quantity Exceeds Parameters." is constant. The subsequent things always change.

I know how to do this using awk `awk '{ idx=index($0,"Adj"); print substr($0,idx); }'`

Perl regex would be good. But not sure how to do this using grep with -P option

I tried the following, but it is not working `grep -Po "'\KAdj.*?(?=')"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I don't understand question, but `grep -oP 'Adj.*'` gives me exactly the same result as `awk '{ idx=index($0,"Adj"); print substr($0,idx); }'`

Comment: I had fixed my answer, grep -oP 'Adj.*' or grep -oP 'Adj.+' works too

Comment: You don't even need `-P` for that; this is a perfectly regular basic regular expression.